# How is the following proof really a proof (inequality)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

[image: Proof]

The user has just subtracted by $\frac{a}{b}$ in the first step and then rearranged the terms to show that it's positive and similar steps have been used to prove the second part of inequality. How is this exactly a proof? How does it make use of the given fact and most importantly, how does it really show what the question has asked?

Comment: Does there miss any conditions like $b\ne0, d\ne0, b+d\ne0$, especially the last one?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question, but $a, b, c$ and $d$ are all positive numbers.

Comment: I hope the image is not from a model solution -- the $\implies$ signs are in the direction where they are useless for establishing the desired property ...

Comment: Ok, it is not a proper proof unless all the $\Rightarrow$ are replaced with $\Leftrightarrow$, yet the user does mean this but not express well.

Comment: Even if they are replaced with the latter symbol, how's it a proper solution?

Comment: I think I see it. If we use the given fact and then divide both sides it by $b(b + d)$ and then proceed backwards, we prove the given relation, right? We just need to change the sign. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As what you wrote, we have
\begin{align}
\frac{a}{b}<\frac{c}{d}
&\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad ad<bc\\
&\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad a(b+d)=ab+ad<ab+bc=b(a+c)\\
&\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad \frac{a}{b}<\frac{a+c}{b+d}.
\end{align}
The other inequality is similar.

Comment: I think I see it. If we use the given fact and then divide both sides it by $b(b+d)$ and then proceed backwards, we prove the given relation, right? We just need to change the sign. Am I correct?

Comment: Your direction is correct.